# web based ssh alternative for java applet

Tags: web, ssh, applet

We are currently working a web based application as alternative for our text based ERP.
We are currently using an applet to open telnet sessions on our servers.
The solution based on the applet is not suitable for the following reasons:

1. It is ugly
2. It has to be signed by a certified authority
3. Users must accept the certificate in order to use the applet

Would it be possible to use any web based ssh client as replacement for the applet.
The application is programmed in Tapestry (3.0.3)
Thank you for your support.

Arthur

Comment: I've been working on a web-based ssh project written in Java EE. Try it out https://github.com/skavanagh/KeyBox There is also other alternatives listed here. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web-based_SSH

Answer (score 1):

Try this site, it's very good..

http://tools.bartlweb.net/webssh/